# line label pie chart graphael

Tags: raphael, graphael

I'm creating a html5 web for mobile device and I'm using graphael to create a pie chart.
The chart is render perfectly but I have two problems that I don't found the solution.

I want that the first portion of the chart start at 12 oclock.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23287638/piechart.png

And my second problem its' that I want to have a line label for each portion of the chart like this:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23287638/chart2.png

Any suggestion to how to do this two things?

Thanks